# In responsive mode my dropdown isn't climbing up

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
include 'includes/head.php';
?>
<body>
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';
?>
```

head.php:-

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>AIT Project</title>
</head>
```

header.php:-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-  target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign  Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
   </nav>
```

As soon as I reduce my display size the bootstrap navbar goes into responsive mode. When I click the button the whole menu drops down but doesn't climb back up.
[responsive navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOiWh.jpg)
Also on dropping down in responsive mode my carousel gets hidden by the navbar
[the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZTmv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo/blank space in `header.php` row 4: `data-  target="#myNavbar"`

...should be `data-target="#myNavbar"`

When fixing that your code is working, see 
https://plnkr.co/edit/gbdhAqbgfvj57BqHzMdV?p=preview A click on the "hamburger menu" to left expands the menu; one more click it collapse. Is this what you want/expect?

Comment: There is no space in my code. When I wrote the code here in the editor the space is coming automatically.

Comment: @AshirogiMuto Ok. If you look in the working plunkr I submitted where the menu expand and collapse as expected, what remains as your problem?

Comment: Great! I'm glad to help!